# Microsoft visual C++ redistributable is not installed, this may lead to the DLL load failure

Tags: visual-c++, pytorch, torch, stable-diffusion, webui

[image: The error that causes my stable broadcast not to work]

I want to tell you that I want to tell you that I installed several versions of Visual C++ Redistributable but it still doesn't work.At the end I also have error [winerror 193] %1 At the end I also get error [winerror 193] %1 is not a valid win32 application

To solve the problem I uninstalled Microsoft visual C++ redistributable and I still installed several other versions but nothing works

At the end I also have error [winerror 193] %1 At the end I also get error [winerror 193] %1 is not a valid win32 application

**What the console shows me**#

venv "C:\Users\Josias\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\Python.exe" Python 3.10.6 (tags/v3.10.6:9c7b4bd, Aug 1 2022, 21:38:17) [MSC v.1932 32 bit (Intel)] Version: v1.5.1 Commit hash: 68f336bd994bed5442ad95bad6b6ad5564a5409a Launching Web UI with arguments: --skip-torch-cuda-test Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable is not installed, this may lead to the DLL load failure. It can be downloaded at https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Users\Josias\stable-diffusion-webui\launch.py", line 39, in  main() File "C:\Users\Josias\stable-diffusion-webui\launch.py", line 35, in main start() File "C:\Users\Josias\stable-diffusion-webui\modules\launch_utils.py", line 390, in start import webui File "C:\Users\Josias\stable-diffusion-webui\webui.py", line 38, in  import torch File "C:\Users\Josias\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\torch_*init*_.py", line 122, in  raise err OSError: [WinError 193] %1 n’est pas une application Win32 valide. Error loading "C:\Users\Josias\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\asmjit.dll" or one of its dependencies. Appuyez sur une touche pour continuer....

Comment: The URL for the redist is wrong, note how the second line in the screenshot tells you that Python is running in 32-bit mode.  So you need the [x86 version](https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vc_redist.x86.exe) of the redist.  193 is an architecture mismatch problem, like a 32-bit program trying to load a 64-bit DLL.   Avoid randomly copying files.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I tried what you suggested but it didn't work still same errors Do I have to uninstall other versions of Visual C++? Or it's the path that is not well configured